# C# Group with conditional

Tags: c#, contains, sqldatareader

how can i grouping a data with conditional if  bill < 10 ?

i have table:

```
meetingId | bill
------------------
     a    |     6
     b    |     7
     c    |     1
     a    |     5
     a    |     3
     b    |     4
     g    |     2
```

expected results : 
a = 6+5+3 = 14 limit is 10 --> 10 and 4 
 b = 7+4 = 11 so limit is 10 --> 10 and 1 
c and g not over the limit.

```
meetingId | bill
------------------
     a    |     10
     a    |     4
     b    |     10
     b    |     1
     c    |     1
     g    |     2
```

i tried in SQL why but i stuck with if condition

my SQL :

```
 SELECT NO_ORDRE
      ,ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT As CodeCl 
      ,[CODE_DEST]  
      ,ORDRE.RS_NOM As OrdreRS
      ,ORDRE.ADRESSE As OrdreAdr
      ,ORDRE.CP As OrdreCP
      ,ORDRE.VILLE As OrdreVille
      ,ENLEV_CREMB
      ,ENLEV_DECL
      ,MODAL_MODE
      ,[PAYS]
      ,[INSEE]
      ,[SIRET]
      ,ORDRE.TEL As OrdreTel
      ,ORDRE.FAX As OrdreFax
      ,[EMAIL]     
      ,[NBR_COLIS]
      ,[POID]   
      ,[OBS]
      ,[DATE_CREE]
      ,[DATE_MODIF]
      ,[REF_EXPED]
      ,[AUTRE_REF]
      ,[AGENCE]
      ,[TRANSPORTEUR]
      ,NOM
      ,CAPITAL
      ,LIBELLE
      ,T_LOGO.IMG As FaImg
      ,T_LOGO.ADRESSE As FaAdr
      ,T_LOGO.CP As FaCp
      ,T_LOGO.VILLE As FaVille
      ,T_LOGO.TEL As FaTel
      ,T_LOGO.FAX As FaFax
      ,FAWEB_CLIENT.RS_NOM As CliRsNom
      ,FAWEB_CLIENT.ADRESSE As CliAdr
      ,FAWEB_CLIENT.CP As CliCp
      ,FAWEB_CLIENT.VILLE As CliVille
  FROM [ORDRE]
  LEFT JOIN T_LOGO ON ORDRE.TRANSPORTEUR = T_LOGO.NOID
  LEFT JOIN FAWEB_CLIENT ON ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT = FAWEB_CLIENT.CODE_CLIENT
 WHERE (STATUT_ORDRE = 2) AND (TRANSPORTEUR IN (SELECT ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@Trans)))
```

and then i use in C#

```
List<Pers_Ordre> oListOrdre = new List<Pers_Ordre>();
                while (readerOne.Read())
                {
                   Pers_Ordre oPerOrdr = new Pers_Ordre();
                   Pers_Ordre test =  (from t in oListOrdre where t.DestId == readerOne["CODE_DEST"].ToString() select t).FirstOrDefault();


                    oPerOrdr.OrdreId = Convert.ToInt32(readerOne["NO_ORDRE"]);
                    oPerOrdr.DestId = readerOne["CODE_DEST"].ToString();

                    if (test == null)
                    {
                        oListOrdre.Add(oPerOrdr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int NbrColis = (from t in oListOrdre where t.DestId == readerOne["CODE_DEST"].ToString() select t.NbrColis).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (NbrColis < 5)
                        {
                            test.NbrColis += NbrColis;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

it not work what i expected.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Can you use LINQ?

Comment: Thanks you for responding. i use the last version of .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Not really an answer, but this doesn't fit in a comment.)</sup>
Here's a LINQ-to-Objects query that groups items by `meetingId` and creates new items such that there is one item with `bill` less than 10 and as many items as needed with `bill` equalling 10 to keep the sum:

[image: Screenshot]

Is this what you're looking for?

<sub>Code:</sub>

```
var list = new List<Tuple<char, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create('a', 6),
    Tuple.Create('b', 7),
    Tuple.Create('c', 1),
    Tuple.Create('a', 5),
    Tuple.Create('a', 3),
    Tuple.Create('b', 4),
    Tuple.Create('g', 2),
};

var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Key = g.Key,
        Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Item2)
    })
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Key = p.Key,
        Items = Enumerable.Repeat(10, p.Sum / 10)
                          .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Sum % 10, 1))
    })
    .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => Tuple.Create(p.Key, i)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this at the client side because it can get pretty intensive, a simple `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause should give you the expected results:

Sample data:

[image]

The query you need:

```
SELECT 
    MeetingID, 
    SUM(bill) AS Total
FROM 
    Table_1 
GROUP BY 
    MeetingID 
HAVING 
    SUM(bill) < 10
```

The results of the query:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you, but i need a--10 and a--2, because a = 5+4+3 = 12, c--10 and c--2, because c = 11+1=12, d--10 and d--2, because d = 12

Comment: I am just using my sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL query will return the wanted results:

```
SELECT meetingId, SUM(bill) as bill_total
FROM table
GROUP BY meetingId
HAVING SUM(bill) < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table.GroupBy(p => p.meetingId).Where(p => p.Sum(q => q.bill) < 10)
.Select(p => new
{
    meetingId= p.Key,
    bill= p.Sum(q => q.bill)
});
```